# Using stl containers with Unreal

Tags: stl, stdvector, unreal-engine4

Can I use std::vector, std::unordered_map instead of TMap, TVector...etc?.

I need a class to serialize all it's info, and I have code that already works with  stl.

I tested trying to use UPROPERTY on them and it's not possible,(Any way to do that?). But I'm ok with that.

What I need to know is **what happens when serializing the whole class when some of it's members are stl containers**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **should not** use them.

> You should not use standard C++ library for other then communicating with external libraries and if you use them you should avoid using UFUNCTION and UPROPERTY on them. 
>   https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/180421/how-to-use-c-standard-library-std.html

If you need to serialize properties, I'd like to propose using Rama's system ([UE Wiki](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Save_System,_Read_%26_Write_Any_Data_to_Compressed_Binary_Files)). I used it in my game to save/load data to binary files, but it could be easily extended to send data over network.

Basically, in that system you are overloading `<<` operator. Pros is that you define all structure in one place and one function could be used both for saving and for loading. *Note* that I've encountered compilation problems when I tried to compile code like:

```
TArray<UObject> array = // init

// ar is container to serialization
ar << array;
```

But I solved it by mapping `UObject`s  to `UStruct`s so code like

```
TArray<FStruct> array = // init

// as is container to serialization
ar << array;     // now, this will compile
```

It was in UE 4.15 and it is possible that it was solved in later versions.

If you want to examine my implementation of Rama's system system more, you can look at my repo of my game [TCF2 (GitHub)](https://github.com/halbich/TauCetiF2/). You are looking for a `/Source/GameSave/[Public|Private]/SaveGameCarrier` - this is my main class for saving. Example of mapping helper could be find in `/Source/Inventory/Public/InventoryHelpers.h`

Comment: Thanks Pavel. Seems like Stack Overflow is much more efficient working as an answer hub than Unreal's :D.  Thanks for the link and the code. TArrays, FVectors, etc, seem efficient enough. I'm working on a very low level software and library and we need extreme optimization. Hopefully they are as good as STL containers.

Comment: Well, you happen to seeking answers that I know. It is only a coincidence that I responded to your last three questions :) About **optimization**: I believe that it is really optimized, since all parts of UE, both engine and also editor, are depending on it. And it is subject to Unreal's memory management, so you don't need to explicitly call `new` and `delete` operators. But if you are working with low-level libraries, you can manage memory by your self, but then you need to implement mechanism to provide data to the engine and game itself.

Comment: If you are seeking for more info about custom memory management, look at https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Garbage_Collection_%26_Dynamic_Memory_Allocation Also, my tip is when you are searching something about UE, try add "rama" to the searching query. Rama has great experience with UE and he also write nice articles about it. (I think that he is one of the UE developers right now).

Comment: Is he working on UE now? I'd hire him, for sure. He's a true legend and helped all the newbies like me. And his yoga videos on youtube are really cool and somehow shocking considering he's a developer too. haha.

Our library manages memory well. My concerns are with Unreal. I'll profile my scenes. It will be a slow process... Thanks!